# No extension while using from_options' in DynamicFrameWriter in AWS Glue spark context

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, aws-glue

```
 I am new to AWS. I am writing **AWS Glue job** for some transformation and I could do it. But now after the transformation I used **'from_options' in DynamicFrameWriter Class** to transfer the data frame as csv file. But the file copied to S3 without any extension. Also is there any way to rename the file copied, using DynamicFrameWriter or any other. Please help....
```

Step1: Triggered an AWS glue job for trnsforming files in S3 to RDS instance..
Step2: On successful job completion transfer the contents of file to another S3 using from_options' in DynamicFrameWriter class. But the file dosen't have any extension.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the format of the file you are writing.
eg: format=csv

This should set the csv file extension.. You however cannot choose the name of the file that you want to write it as. The only option you have is to have some sort of s3 operation where you change the key name of the file.

Comment: What type of S3 operaion you suggest? can we do it in glue job itself (Spark context)?

Comment: have set the format =csv , but then also the  resulting file has no extension.

Comment: S3 resource in boto3 has copy functions u can use

Comment: Yes, I have checked that with lamda function and was successful.But actually the problem that I face is – Step 1: Upload files to S3 bucket1. Step 2: Trigger lamda function to call Job1 Step 3: On success of job1 transfer file to S3 bucket2 Step 4: On failure transfer to another S3 bucket.    I can do this with cloudwatch events, for getting the job status, but I wont get the file name that has been processed, since there can be multiple files in S3 at a time, may be transfered with FTP file transfer.  Can you please help me..

Comment: Could you say exactly whcih step u are having trouble with.. Is it Step 3 and 4 where you actually need to move the files ? If so... you can make it as part of your glue code, when you encounter an exception (try..catch..), catch that exception and move that file to the faliure path...On success, the same thing, move the processed files to the path you want...

Comment: Yes I think I can place try catch and do the transfer. But I am doing glue job in spark context, so I need some code in spark context for this transfer. Is there any solution?? please help.............

Comment: Glue is nothing more than a wrapper on spark which in turn runs on python. So anything u write using python works on your glue script.

Comment: i tried like this. But there happened some connection issue (When calling lambda function from glue job) . Where i should look for rectifying this?

Comment: U don’t need to write a separate lambda and call it in glue. Just write your python code in the glue script itself to achieve what u need to do.

Comment: Also, please share any code u wrote so We get a clearer understanding of what exactly you are having problems with

Comment: I tried with what u told and at first it didn't worked since I was not using the root user. When I tried with root user everything worked fine. Now I can call lambda function from glue job and also could write python code using boto3 client from within the job.

Comment: Cool. Looks like you are getting somewhere. I’m not sure about how you run your jobs and how the permissions are setup and I would be looking at why a root user is required to run jobs./ lambdas

Comment: its not required to run job/lambda. But what I meant is  to call a lambda/webservice from a glue job I require a root user.